# ResponseEntity o @ResponseBody en respuestas http de api

Tags: java, http

Tengo una duda sobre documentaciones y no se realmente cual usar si los dos o uno solo pero no se cual.
Si retorno un objeto con atributos get y set o una lista o una cadena String cual debería usar.
No entiendo muy bien la diferencia y en que escenarios usar cual
Lo echo de estas maneras.

@ResponseBody: lo eh usado para retornas listas, objetos o cadenas

```
    @GetMapping("/listas/{tipolista}")
    @ResponseBody
    private List<CUsuarioVO> responseListusuarios(@PathVariable(required = true) String tipolista) {
        CConsume.restUsuario();
        List<CUsuarioVO> lista = CUsuarioDAO.getListausuarios(tipolista);
        return lista;
    }
```

@Responsebody y ResponseEntity.OK para una cadena u objetos

```
@PostMapping("/agregar")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<String> addUsuarios(@RequestBody CUsuarioVO usvo) {
        String response = null;
        try {
            if (usvo.getUsnombres() != "" && usvo.getUsapellidos() != "" && usvo.getUstelefono() != ""
                    && usvo.getUscorreo() != "" && usvo.getUsclave() != "" && usvo.getUsapellidos() != ""
                    && usvo.getUsrol() != "") {

                if (validarCorreo(usvo.getUscorreo(), null) == true) {
                    response = daous.addUsuario(usvo) == true ? "agregado" : "noagregado";
                } else {
                    response = "correoexiste";
                }
            } else {
                response = "datosincompletos";
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.print("Error aca al algregar el usuario: "+e);
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok(response);
    }
```

Con solo responseEntity.ok(Objeto a retornar)

```
@GetMapping("/login")
    private ResponseEntity<CUsuarioVO> responseLogin(@RequestParam(required = true) String correo,
            @RequestParam(required = true) String clave) {
        vousuario = CUsuarioDAO.validarUsuario(correo, clave);
        if (vousuario.getUsid() != null) {
            token = JWTAuthorizationFilter.getTokenUsuario(vousuario.getUsid());
            vousuario.setUstoken(token);
        }

        return ResponseEntity.ok(vousuario);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

La anotación @ResponseBody te permite evitar el uso de ResponseEntity, por ejemplo:

Si usas la anotación, el código simplemente quedaría así:

```
@ResponseBody
public List<String> function() {...}
```

Si no usas la anotación, la función debería ser así:

```
public ResponseEntity<List<String>> function() {...}
```

ResponseEntity es un objeto que envuelve a List y que te permite manejar la respuesta HTTP. Si usas la anotación, esto se hace automáticamente por eso no es necesario poner explícitamente ResponseEntity<List>. En caso de no usarla, sí que se debe poner.

La diferencia entre ambas, es que usar ResponseEntity, dará mayor flexibilidad para manejar la respuesta HTTP.